# How is if (cin) { while(cin)... Works?

Tags: c++

```
int main () {
int num1, num2;
int cnt = 1;
    if (cin >> num1){       
        while (cin >> num2){
              if (num1==num2){
                  ++cnt;
              } else {
                  cout << num1 << " is " << cnt << " times" << endl;
                  cnt = 1;
                  num1 = num2;
              }
        }
    }
    cout << num1 << " is " << cnt << "-times" << endl;
}
```

This code accepts a  line of numbers and outputs how many times each number was entered. What I dont understand is why there is `num1=num2`. With removing it program outputs the first number which was entered, which lead me to believe that I don't know how `cin` works in loops.

What I think now is that first digit goes into `if (cin >> num1),` and it keeps sitting here and next same digits don't overwriting `num1` integer. Second and the rest digits going into `while (cin >> num2)` overwriting it every time until there is a different number, which makes `else` to execute and it outputs number which was stored in `num1` the whole time.

With *`num1=num2`* it changes *`num1`* in `if(cin>> num1)` and the whole thing starts again.
Am I right?

Which also strange that the very last cout may sure inside of first  **`if`** body, and it may not, it works anyway...

Edit1: with num1=num2; I input 1 1 2 2 3 3 3, as one line, it outputs

```
1 is 2 times

2 is 2 times

3 is 3 times.
```

Without num1=num1;

```
1 is 2 times

1 is 1 times

1 is 1 times

1 is 1 times

1 is 1 times
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin >> num1` tries to read a number from the standard input into the `num1` variable. If that succeeds, the body of the `if` will be executed. Otherwise (e.g. if the user entered something other than a number or pressed Ctrl-d/Ctrl-z right away), we jump directly to the code after the `if`. This happens exactly once.

`cin >> num2` does the same thing with the `num2` variable, except this time it's inside a `while` instead of an `if`. So if the input operations succeeds, the body of the while loop executes and `cin >> num2` is then executed again until it eventually fails.

> What I dont understand is why there is `num1=num2`.

As I said, `cin >> num1` only executes once (it's not inside any loop). So if you never re-assign `num1`, it will always keep the first value that was entered. But you don't want that, you want it to contain the value you're currently counting. That's why that assignment is there.

> With num1=num2 it changes num1 in if(cin>> num1) and the whole thing starts again. Am I right?

No, `cin >> num1` never executes again. It's not inside a loop. Only `cin >> num2` is executed multiple time because that one's part of the `while` loop.

> Which also strange that the very last cout may sure inside of first if body, and it may not, it works anyway...

If the first input operation fails, it will jump to the outside of the body right away. If the `cout` statement is there, that will mean that it will be executed even if the first input failed. In that case `num1` will be uninitialized, so using it will invoke undefined behaviour. Therefore that statement should not be outside of the `if`.

Comment: bist Du das, SeppJ? O.O

Comment: @Swordfish Nö, I've never used the nickname SeppJ nor does my last name start with J.

Comment: Ok, I see. 42. 15 characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int num1, num2;
    int cnt = 1;
    if (std::cin >> num1) { // if a valid integer can be extracted from cin
        while (std::cin >> num2) { // do as long as valid integers are extracted from cin
            if (num1 == num2) { // if the first extracted int matches the next one
                ++cnt; // increase the count
            }
            else { // if it is a different int then do some output and
                std::cout << num1 << " is " << cnt << " times\n";
                cnt = 1; // reset the counter and
                num1 = num2; // remember the new extracted number for
                             // the next iteration of the while-loop
                             // since only num2 will be read again from cin
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << num1 << " is " << cnt << "-times\n";
}
```

Since the last line in `main()` is meaningless if there is no valid input i'd advocate for early exit:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    // ...
    if (!( std::cin >> num1 ))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (std::cin >> num2) {
        if (num1 == num2) {
    //  ...
```

it also reduces indentation levels and thus enhances readability.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand the code does is calculate and display the number of *consecutive* appearances of a number, so it wouldn't work for an unordered list.

That said, how it works is essentially as follows:

1. See if there is a number available in the stream, and if so, store it in `num1`.
2. For each following number, read the number to `num2`.
3. If `num1` and `num2` are the same, increment the counter.
4. If, however, the numbers are not the same: output the repeat count, set the counter to 1, *and* change the first number of comparison (`num1`) to the newly read number (`num2`).

Answer (score 0):

The first if `if (cin >> num1)` checks if there was an input (waits for the input, of course) into num1, only then will it continue to the loop.

Then it waits for the second input into num2 and enters the loop, if the input is empty.

Then it compares the two inputs. If they're the same... it increments the counter.
Otherwise, it will output how many times that same input was detected in a row **and then change the comparing input to the last entered value** and repeat the loop, waiting for an input.

So it compares how many times after another you're providing the same input...

Basically if the input is:

```
5
5
5
1
```

The output will be "5 is 3 times"

and if the input is

```
1
5
5
5
```

The output will be "1 is 1 times"